# Where does a device file come from?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, drivers, devices

I'm reading through the [Linux Kernel Module programming guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x569.html) and I am a bit onfused about how device drivers work.

I tried following along and making a basic device driver, which shows up in /proc/devices, which is great. According to the guide, to interface with the driver in Linux, a userspace program can interact with that device's device file in /dev/. Right now though, the module I've written doesn't generate a device file. What manages the generation of new files? Is that something I'm supposed to do in module_init?

And assuming I've gone and gotten a device file made, is interacting with the driver, in say a C++ program, just opening up an fstream and reading or writing that file, or are there specific libraries used to interact with device files in userspace?

Comment: Classically, you use the `mknod` command to create the device file with the correct major and minor device numbers.  Programs then interact with your device driver by opening the device and using the read, write, seek, close system calls.  Remember, on UNIX-like systems, everything's a file.

Comment: Another interesting thing to do with most device files is to call `ioctl()` with driver specific parameters.

Comment: To make a device file magically appear (through udev) you must - as far as I understand it - trigger certain uevents.

Comment: So what calls mknod? I could do it manually from the terminal, but I never do that for  other stuff like plugging in a usb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files in `/dev` are mostly created by the `udev` process which receives events from the kernel by listening to the `netlink` socket for `NETLINK_KOBJECT_UEVENT` (see `man 7 netlink`). The events are sent when a new kernel object (kobject) is created. These objects are also seen in the `/sys` sysfs filesystem. In particular, files named `dev` in the `/sys/devices` subtree hold the major and minor number of the node to use for a given device. Eg

```
$ cat /sys/devices/pnp0/00:05/tty/ttyS0/dev
4:64
```

This is explained in this online [chapter 14 pdf](http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/linuxdrive3/book/ch14.pdf) of *Linux Device Drivers, Third Edition*
from 2005, *The Linux Device Model*. It is a little outdated and does not mention `netlink` for example.

Comment: Ok, I followed some other references and found the libraries that register a device for  you so now I have a device file. So is there ever actually anything IN that file, or is it just a transfer to the driver? I tried making a program that just opens an fstream to the device file, writes a thing into it, and closes it. Then when I cat /var/log/messages, I see the message that my driver is supposed to report when it gets read, so that seemed to work. But if I cat the actual file itself, it's empty.

Comment: As you say, a `cat` of your `/dev` file just calls your read() routine. You should then use `copy_to_user()` to copy data to the user provided buffer, and return the number of bytes copied. See chapter 3 [of the same book](http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/linuxdrive3/book/) and the `scull_read()` example.